# How can i add a watermark on videos?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

This is my code that i'm using to merge videos .

```
 var_dump(shell_exec( "C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe -f concat -safe 0 -i   D:/xampp/htdocs/test/file.txt -c copy D:/xampp/htdocs/test/phpconcatenated.mp4 2>&1"));
```

But this code is working only when all videos is with same number of frames/second . and if frames per second are different for each other then it merge videos with only sounds with pause screen .